# JPA 2.0 disable session cache for unit tests

Tags: java, unit-testing, jpa, translation

I am writing unit test for my services e. g. :

```
@Test
@Rollback(value = true)
public void testMethod()
{
   // insert test data

    myService.Method(); // read/write from DB

   // asserts go here
}
```

While application running, a new transaction is created every time method A entered. But during the unit test execution  - when test testMethod entered. So method A doesn't create new one.
  For proper testing I need to clear cache before every call to service inside test.I don't want to write Session.clear() before any call to service in each unit test. What is the best best practices here?

Comment: Oops, didn't pay attention to the actual title. I did some cursory searching and the stateless session may be what you want to use. http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/batch.html#batch-statelesssession

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The EntityManager has a method [clear()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#clear%28%29) that will drop all persistence context:

> Clear the persistence context, causing all managed entities to become detached. Changes made to entities that have not been flushed to the database will not be persisted.

If you call a query right after that method it will come directly from the database. Not from a cache.

If you want to run this before every test, consider using a JUnit [@Rule](http://junit.org/javadoc/4.10/org/junit/Rule.html) by subclassing [ExternalResource](http://junit.org/javadoc/4.10/org/junit/rules/ExternalResource.html) and running the method on every `before()` or `after()`. You can reuse that in al you database tests.

Answer (score 2):

There are several way:

1. Evict Caches Manually

   ```
   @Autowired private CacheManager cacheManager;

   public void evictAllCaches(){ 
      for(String name : cacheManager.getCacheNames()){
         cacheManager.getCache(name).clear(); 
      } 
   }
   ```
2. Turning Off Cache for Integration Test Profile

   - for Spring Boot: `spring.cache.type=NONE`
   - or

```
        /** * Disabling cache for integration test */ 
        @Bean public CacheManager cacheManager() {
           return new NoOpCacheManager(); 
        }
```

3. Use `@DirtiesContext`

   ```
   @DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
   class CacheAffectedTest { ...
   ```

In this case Spring context re-created after every test and test's time in my measure tripling.

4. For developing [Spring Boot Dev Tools](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-devtools) turns caching off automatically during the development phase.

See [Spring Cache and Integration Testing](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-cache-and-integration-testing) and [A Quick Guide to @DirtiesContext](https://www.javarticles.com/2016/03/spring-dirtiescontext-annotation-example.html)